# Probability of raining on at least X days, given probability of raining for each day?

Tags: probability

If the odds of raining are 3/11 on Monday, 3/11 on Tuesday, 3/11 on Wednesday, and 2/11 on Thursday, what are the odds of raining on at least two of these four days?

What are the odds of raining on at least three of these four days?

Comment: The word "odds" and the word "probability" are *not* the same.  The probability of rolling a six on a fair six-sided die is $\frac{1}{6}$.  The *odds* on the other hand are $5:1$ against.  If you want to be talking about probability, then *only* use the word probability.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Should we assume that the events described are independent of one another?  That is not a safe assumption in the real world as if it rainy one day it is more likely it will be rainy again the next day too than usual.  It so happens that your probabilities add up to $1$ as well, I suppose that is merely coincidence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we calculate the probability of it raining any two of the days. The probability that it will rain on just Monday and Tuesday is:
$$\left(\frac{3}{11}\cdot \frac{3}{11}\right)\cdot \left(\frac{8}{11}\cdot \frac{9}{11}\right) = \frac{648}{14461}=:a$$
The probability that it will rain on just Wednesday and Thursday is:
$$\left(\frac{3}{11}\cdot \frac{2}{11}\right)\cdot \left(\frac{8}{11}\cdot \frac{8}{11}\right) = \frac{384}{14641}=:b$$
So the probability that it will rain on just two of the days is $3a+3b \approx 0.2131$ (since Monday & Tuesday = Monday & Wednesday = Tuesday & Wednesday, and Wednesday & Thursday = Tuesday & Thursday = Monday & Thursday).

Now, the probability that it will rain Monday, Tuesday, and Wednesday is
$$\left( \frac{3}{11} \right)^3\cdot \frac{9}{11} = \frac{243}{14641}=:c$$
The probability that it will rain Tuesday, Wednesday, and Thursday is
$$ \left(\frac{3}{11}\cdot \frac{3}{11}\cdot \frac{2}{11}\right) \cdot \frac{8}{11} = \frac{144}{14641}=:d$$
So, the probability that it will rain on just three of the days is $c+3d \approx 0.0461$ (since Tuesday&Wednesday&Thursday = Monday&Wednesday&Thursday = Monday&Tuesday&Thursday).

Finally, the probability that it will rain on all four of the days is

$$\frac{3}{11}\cdot \frac{3}{11}\cdot \frac{3}{11}\cdot \frac{2}{11} \approx 0.0036$$

So, $0.2131 + 0.0461 + 0.0036 = 0.2628$.